# Custom Word Breaker for Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, search, registry

I'm finding a lot of articles which explain how to change the Sharepoint 2013 Word Breakers via the Registry. However, I'm not sure what values I should be putting in the WBreakerClass fields.

I'd like to change my Word Breakers to allow users to Search using the dash/hyphen "-" character. How can I do this via the Registry? Is there a list of Word Breaker classes I can reference to update the Value?